# Dropzonejs, removes from server not from the page

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, drag

I am using dropzonejs and it works in the server, It saves and when I click on the remove button it removes from the server. But the only problem is, when I click to remove button the picture stays on the page. I think it is because of the jquery code. But I could not solve it.

Here ;

```
<div class="container">

<%= form_for [@boat, @picture], html: { multipart: true, url: wizard_path, class: "dropzone", id: "picture-dropzone"} do |f| %>


      <p>

      <div class="fallback">
      <%= f.file_field :image %> 

      </div>    

      </p>

<% end %>

<p><%= link_to "Back to My Profile",  current_user %></p>


<div class="index">
  <%= render "index" %>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    // disable auto discover
    Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;

    // grap our upload form by its id
    $("#picture-dropzone").dropzone({
        // restrict image size to a maximum 5MB
        maxFilesize: 5,
        // changed the passed param to one accepted by
        // our rails app
        paramName: "picture[image]",

        acceptedFiles: "image/*", 
        // show remove links on each image upload
        addRemoveLinks: false,
        // if the upload was successful
        success: function(file, response){
            // find the remove button link of the uploaded file and give it an id
            // based of the fileID response from the server
            $(file.previewTemplate).find('.dz-remove').attr('id', response.fileID);
            $(file.previewTemplate).find('.dz-remove').attr('boat_id', response.boatID);
            // add the dz-success class (the green tick sign)
            $(file.previewElement).addClass("dz-success");

        },
        //when the remove button is clicked
        removedfile: function(file){

            // grap the id of the uploaded file we set earlier
            var id = $(file.previewTemplate).find('.dz-remove').attr('id'); 
            var boat_id = $(file.previewTemplate).find('.dz-remove').attr('boat_id'); 
            // make a DELETE ajax request to delete the file
            $.ajax({
            type: 'DELETE',
                url: '/boats/' + boat_id + '/pictures/' + id,
                success: function(file){
                 removeFile(file); // THIS DOES NOT WORK

                    //SOMETHING HERE

                }
            });
        }
    }); 
});



</script>
```